# Lagrange Interpolation Basic Proof

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

I have been given this question, and I am unsure what the intuition behind answering it would be, nor where to start:

> Let $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$. Show that, for some given function $f$, the polynomial
> $$P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) L_k(x), \quad\text{where}\quad L_k(x) = \prod_{i=1\\i\neq k}^n \dfrac{x-x_i}{x_k-x_i}$$, satisfies $$P(x) = f(x) \quad \text{for} \quad x=x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n.$$

How would one approach this question, and what does it intuitively show by answering it?

Comment: Show first $L_k(x_j)=0$ for $j\ne k$, then compute $L_k(x_k)=1$ and you are done.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How can I show that $L_k(x_j) = 0$ for $j \neq k$? Is this just quoting the definition of a Lagrange polynomial?

Comment: The product in the definition of $L_k$ gets a factor that is zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Would it be possible to construct an answer? My understanding of this topic is quite limited at the moment so I struggle to fully grasp what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that $L_k(x_j)=\delta_{jk}$ with the Kronecker delta. The zeros originate with zeros of the linear factors in the defining product of $L_k(x)$, while the ones result from cancellation in the quotient factors of the product.

So in the end you compute $P(x_j)=\sum_k\delta_{kj}f(x_j)=f(x_j)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry if I am being stupid, but I still don't understand. I know that $L_k(x_j)$ will either take values of $0$ or $1$, as you mentioned with the Kronecker delta. But how does this prove that the satisfication is met of $P(x) = f(x)$ for $x = x_1, \dots , x_n$ ?

Comment: Because this simply means $P(x_j)=f(x_j)$ for $j=1,...,n$.